# np.fromregex with string as dtype

Tags: python, regex, numpy

I have a file with dates formatted as "1:*? year mo da ho mi se.condsdec", (with "?" being a 1 character wildcard) ie:

```
*A 2014 12 31 23 59 59.123456
```

I would like to extract this either as strings (to eventually be converted to datetime strings).

I am able to extract the date as a set of `int`/`floats` using the regex pattern:

```
time_pattern=r'\*.{2}(\d{4}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}\.\d{8})'
```

but not as a string. How do I get this to work using a string?

I am using python 3.4.3 with numpy 1.9.3.

```py
import numpy as np
time_pattern=r'\*.{2}(\d{4}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}\.\d{8})'
t_dtype=[('year',np.int16),('month',np.int8),('day',np.int8),\
('hour',np.int8),('min',np.int8),('sec',np.float64)]
out=np.fromregex('filename',time_pattern,t_dtype)
print(out)
#returns [(2013, 11, 26, 0, 0, 10.0) (2013, 11, 26, 0, 0, 20.0)
# (2013, 11, 26, 0, 0, 30.0)]


basic_t=r'$\*.{2}(.{28})'
t_dtype=[('date',str)]
out=np.fromregex('filename',basic_t,t_dtype)
#causes TypeError: 
#TypeError: Empty data-type
```

using a file `filename`:

```
*  2003 11 26 00 00 10.00000000  
some text or interesting data                      
*  2003 11 26 00 00 20.00000000
more text
even more text                         
*  2003 11 26 00 00 30.00000000    
etc.
```

Edit: Note that the pattern in a simple

```py
with open(file) as f: 
   for line in f: 
      m=re.search(basic_t,line)
```

But I would like to have the output as a numpy array, and would like to keep runtime to a minimum.

Edit Edit:
Changing dtype to `'S'` or `np.str` removes the error, but I still get an empty list as output

Comment: If I do that I seem to get empty strings as output. ie. if I turn year and month to `np.str` I get output like `('', '', 26, 0, 0, 10.0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are setting the dtype as int or float when you should be specifying them as `np.str_`. You also need to specify the length of the string so

```
import numpy as np

time_pattern=r'\*.{2}(\d{4}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}\.\d{8})'
t_dtype=[('year',np.str_,4),('month',np.str_,2),('day',np.str_,2),\
('hour',np.str_,2),('min',np.str_,2),('sec',np.str_,3)]

out=np.fromregex('filename',time_pattern,t_dtype)
print(out)
```

If you look at the second example of [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), it shows how to handle strings