# How to read data nicely using np.fromregex?

Tags: python, numpy

I am little bit familiar with np.fromregex. I read the tutorials and tried to implement it to read a data file.

When the file is read using simple python list comprehension, it gives the desired result:
`[400, 401, 405, 408, 412, 414, 420, 423, 433]`.

But, when `np.fromregex` is is gives another format answer:
`[(400,) (401,) (405,) (408,) (412,) (414,) (420,) (423,) (433,)]`.

How can the code be changed so that the answer from regex becomes same as the simple python for loop.

Thanks.

P.S. I know this is a simple question but it took me a lot of time to look for
the solution and it might be benificial to others too and save some time.

Related links:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html
[np.fromregex with string as dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014828/np-fromregex-with-string-as-dtype)

```
from __future__ import print_function, division, with_statement, unicode_literals
import numpy as np
import re

data = """
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_400.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_401.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_405.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_408.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_412.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_414.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_420.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_423.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_433.fits
"""

ifile = 'a.txt'
with open(ifile, 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(data.lstrip())


# regex
regexp = r".*_(\d+?).fits"

# This works fine
ans = [int(re.findall(regexp, line)[0]) for line in open(ifile)]
print(ans)

# using fromregex
dt = [('num', np.int32)]
x = np.fromregex(ifile, regexp, dt)
print(x)
```

**Update**
The above code failed when I used the future imports. The error log is given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 31, in <module>
    x = np.fromregex(ifile, regexp, dt)
  File "/Users/poudel/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1452, in fromregex
    dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: data type not understood


$ which python
python is /Users/poudel/miniconda2/bin/python 

$ python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"
1.14.0
```

Comment: `print(repr(x))` gives a clearer idea of what `x` is - including the `dt` dtype.

Comment: `x` is a `structured array` as specified in the `fromregex` docs.  The `[(400,),...]` list of tuples is the standard way of displaying such an array.  You access `fields` of such an array by name, e.g. `x['num']`, where 'num' is specified in the `dt` line.  The result will be an array of `int32` values.

Comment: Thanks a lot @hpaulj, The above code works fine but when I use `from __future__ import print_function, division, with_statement, unicode_literals`, it fails. does fromregex also work in python3 ?

Comment: It works for me in PY3 - without the `from __future__`.  What's the nature of the `fails`?

Comment: @hpaulj, I have edited the question. Again, It worked also for me for py3.6 but failed for py2.7 with __future__.

Comment: I suspect a bytestring vs unicode difference, but I don't have `numpy` installed for Py2 so can't help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just choose the group and you'll get what you want:

```
dt = [('num', np.int32)]
x = np.fromregex(ifile, regexp, dt)
print(x['num'])
#[400 401 405 408 412 414 420 423 433]
```

Comment: it failed when I used `from __future__ import print_function, division, with_statement, unicode_literals`.  Is this also possible in python3 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cStringIO
import re

data = """
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_400.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_401.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_405.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_408.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_412.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_414.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_420.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_423.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_433.fits
"""

# ifile = cStringIO.StringIO()
# ifile.write(data)
ifile = 'a.txt'
with open(ifile, 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(data.lstrip())


# regex
regexp = r".*_(\d+?).fits"

# This works fine
ans = [int(re.findall(regexp, line)[0]) for line in open(ifile)]
print(ans)

# using fromregex
dt = [('num', np.int32)]
x = np.fromregex(ifile, regexp, dt)
y=[]
for i in x:
    y = y + [i[0]]
print y

"""
[400, 401, 405, 408, 412, 414, 420, 423, 433]
[400, 401, 405, 408, 412, 414, 420, 423, 433]
"""
```

I am not aware of doing this without a loop.

Comment: You don't have to create y, this method is already given in the question, just look at the line `print(ans)`.

Answer (score 0):

All the thanks goes to @zipa and @hpaulj, Finally this code works for
python2 with future statements. It also works for python3.

Instead of `dt = [('num', np.int32)]` we need to use `dt = [(str('num'), np.int32)]`.

```
#!python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-#
#
# Imports
from __future__ import print_function, division, with_statement, unicode_literals
import numpy as np
import re

data = """
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_400.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_401.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_405.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_408.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_412.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_414.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_420.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_423.fits
DMStack failed for: lsst_z1.0_433.fits
"""

ifile = 'a.txt'
with open(ifile, 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(data.lstrip())


# regex
regexp = r".*_(\d+?).fits"
dt = [(str('num'), np.int32)]
x = np.fromregex(ifile, regexp, dt)
print(x['num'])
```